# How make VirtualBox share virtual machine list in a dual boot system (Windows 7 and Ubuntu)?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

I want VirtualBox on Ubuntu display the VMs I created while running VirtualBox in Windows 7, I'm working with a dual boot PC. Windows 7 partition is accessible and writable from my Ubuntu and I changed the *Default Machine Folder* options of the Ubuntu VirtualBox to point to:

> /mnt/92FA7233FA721427/Users/MyUserName/VirtualBox VMs

and still not show the VMs that are there. To show the VMs created while I was logged in Windows I must re-add them in Ubuntu (CTRL-A). Maybe the VM list is stored in some configuration file, but I don't know which one.

Where VirtualBox store the list of VMs? What I must do to after I create a VM in Windows it appear in Ubuntu without have to re-add it?

Answer (score 0):

Open Virtualbox and a filemanager window. Point filemanager window to where your VMs are stored. Drag and drop desired .vbox files to Virtualbox list area.

Comment: Thanks, but exist a way to keep the list synchronized automatically? I mean, each time I add a VM to Windows 7, see it automatically in Ubuntu. I we can figure out in what file the list is stored, we keep the file synchronized automatically or better, share it between the two VirtualBox installation. The point of my question is not make visible VMs created on windows 7, but **share the VM list**